# Two redirect rules conflict with each other .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I had problems with a .htaccess file, that has been fixed, now i have another problem. I wish to clean the url using a .htaccess file. here is my current rule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?a=page&b=([^&]+)[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?a=page&b=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will clean page links to point to a clean url that have a link containing `a=page`. It works perfectly. I tried to add another rule so that it applies to links containing `a=rpofile` but it did not work. However it does work if i remove the above code. It seems that i can not have both rules running at the same time. Below is the `a=profile` version of the above code.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?a=profile&u=([^&]+)[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If URL is `/about` then first rule will forward to `/index.php?a=page&b=about` now same `/about` cannot be forwarded to `/index.php?a=profile&b=about`.

**But you can have `/profile/something` be treated as profile URL.**

You can have 2 rules as:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?a=page&b=([^\s&]+)[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?a=page&b=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?a=profile&u=([^\s&]+)[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks again! it works great. One quick question, could i have `/profile/something` instead of `/p/something`? I tried changing where you have put `p` eg `RewriteRule ^ /profile/%1? [R=301,L]` and `RewriteRule ^profile/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?a=profile&u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` but it did not work. Thanks again.